# R: Automate Extraction of Linear Regression Equation from lm

Tags: r, linear-regression, lm

Does anyone know of an existing function to extract the full linear equation from a lm object?

Suppose I have:

```
lm1 = lm(y~x1+x2...xn, data=df)
```

For this course in regression I'm taking, the professor repeatedly wants the resulting regression equation in the form: e(y) = b1 +b2x1 [...] bnx(n-1).

Currently, I am doing something like this:

```
(paste("y=", coef(lm1)[1], '+', coef(lm1[2]), '*x2', [...])
```

It has carried on for weeks like this.  It would not be a huge problem to copy and paste the paste function above, but he wants the actual variable labels in there instead of y,x1, etc.  As you can see, my hand and mind are hurting from repeatedly doing this.

I have crossed my pain threshold for this and today started to think about to create my own function for this, but I'm just checking to see if anyone knows of an existing function that does this automatically.

I don't think it will be exceptionally difficult to create a function that does the same paste function except on a variable length for the number of coefficients, but it's just something where I would rather go with an existing solution given the end product is such a useless construct.

Note:  this is quite similar but also not quite the same question as posed here:
[Extract Formula From lm with Coefficients (R)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21269793/extract-formula-from-lm-with-coefficients-r)

Why is it different?  That questions addresses a one off case of, "how do you extract a linear regression equation from an lm object?"  This question is, "is there a an existing base method or (if not) a method for **systematically** getting the linear regression equation from an lm object.  This is especially apparent when you see the answer posed here versus the accepted answer on the other page.

Comment: See here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21269793/extract-formula-from-lm-with-coefficients-r

Comment: Thanks, I saw that one, but I figured there had to be an existing built in function for this.  I guess I'm just going to have to modify that one to get one that can adjust for the correct number of predictors.

Comment: Actually, the code in the linked SO post automatically adjusts for the number of predictors.

Comment: I made a new answer to the post you referenced where the solution is very versatile. No `paste0` needed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My naive approach to this problem would also be to customize my own function using `paste0()`:

```
regEq <- function(lmObj, dig) {
    paste0("y = ",
        paste0(
            c(round(lmObj$coef[1], dig), round(sign(lmObj$coef[-1])*lmObj$coef[-1], dig)),
            c("", rep("*", length(lmObj$coef)-1)),
            paste0(c("", names(lmObj$coef)[-1]), c(ifelse(sign(lmObj$coef)[-1]==1," + "," - "), "")),
            collapse=""
        )
    )
}
```

where it gets a little messy because of the signs and intercept. Lets look at a simple call:

```
> fit <- lm(-mpg ~ cyl + hp + drat, data=mtcars)
> fit

Call:
lm(formula = -mpg ~ cyl + hp + drat, data = mtcars)

Coefficients:
(Intercept)          cyl           hp         drat  
  -22.51406      1.36060      0.02878     -2.84090  

> regEq(fit,3)
[1] "y = -22.514 + 1.361*cyl + 0.029*hp - 2.841*drat"
```

EDIT:
wrt. comment: In order to replace `y` with the variable name and change the interaction operator to `*` rewrite:

```
regEq <- function(lmObj, dig) {
    gsub(":", "*", 
        paste0(
            names(lmObj$model)[1]," = ",
            paste0(
                c(round(lmObj$coef[1], dig), round(sign(lmObj$coef[-1])*lmObj$coef[-1], dig)),
                c("", rep("*", length(lmObj$coef)-1)),
                paste0(c("", names(lmObj$coef)[-1]), c(ifelse(sign(lmObj$coef)[-1]==1," + "," - "), "")),
                collapse=""
            )
        )
    )
}

> regEq(lm(mpg ~ hp * drat, data=mtcars), 3)
[1] "mpg = 5.55 - 0.013*hp + 6.069*drat - 0.01*hp*drat"
```

Comment: That works!  I can't see why it works though.  It looks like with the -1 you would get the last coefficient in the lmobject but it behaves something similar to the for i in (1:length(lm_object)) loop I was working on.  I'm trying to take apart your solution so that I could (potentially) modify for interactive terms.  It would replace "x1:x2" with x1*x2.  Also looking into modifying so that the actual name of the y variable shows up in the equation instead of just "y".  Both points are fairly trivial, but it's a fairly trivial class....

Comment: @nordicray had to do some work arounds with the intercept, that's the reason for [-1]. Split the inside `paste` if you want to make sense of it. Also made an edit wrt. your comment.

Comment: Thanks again!  I was headed down a much more burdensome path.  I was going to replace the "y=" with a call to function another function I found on stack overflow:

    getResponse <- function(formula) {
    tt <- terms(formula)
    vars <- as.character(attr(tt, "variables"))[-1] ## [1] is the list call
    response <- attr(tt, "response") # index of response var
    vars[response]}

I had done quite a lot of searching for trying to extract the y variable and used str(lm_object) about 20 times but couldn't get to it.  I had no idea it was in $model.

Comment: I have uprooted this solution but my votes do not count yet.