# Is there any way to construct real regression equation by taking parameters from models in R?

Tags: r, statistics, regression, formula

data is:

```
d <- data.frame(x = rnorm(100, 0, 1),
            y = rnorm(100, 0, 1),
            z = rnorm(100, 0, 1))
```

## function to fit 5 models

```
library(splines)
func <-function(d){
  fit1 <- lm( y~ x + z, data = d)
  fit2 <- lm( y~x + I(z^2), data = d)
  fit3 <- lm( y~poly(x,3) + z, data = d)
  fit4 <- lm( y~ns(x, 3) + z, data = d)
  l <- list(fit1, fit2, fit3, fit4)
  names(l) <- paste0("fit", 1:4) 
  return(l)
}

mods <- func(d) 
mods[[1]]

stargazer(mods, type="text)
```

I want to construct real regression equations in real format of each one of the models by taking parameters from fitting models and ind variables automatically inside of R if it is possible. For example: for fit1 model, intercept = -0.20612, x = 0.17443, x = 0.03203. Then equation will be something like this: y = -0.206 + 0.174x + 0.032z etc and wanna list these equations of all models in a table along with very common useful statistics like R2, P value, adj.R2, observations etc. stargazer is not showing me my desired output. So I wanna make sure if there is any way to do this in R without doing it manually in excel?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can `map` through *mods* using @`J.R.`'s function [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31770729/r-automate-extraction-of-linear-regression-equation-from-lm?noredirect=1&lq=1) and `broom::glance` to the model R2, P-value, and adj.R2.

```
library(purrr)
library(broom)
map_dfr(mods, 
        function(x) data.frame('Eq'=regEq(lmObj = x, dig = 3), broom::glance(x), stringsAsFactors = FALSE), 
        .id='Model') 

  Model                                                                              Eq    r.squared adj.r.squared    sigma  statistic   p.value df    logLik      AIC      BIC
1  fit1                                                   y = 0.091 - 0.022*x - 0.027*z 0.0012601436   -0.01933243 1.028408 0.06119408 0.9406769  3 -143.1721 294.3441 304.7648
2  fit2                                              y = 0.093 - 0.022*x - 0.003*I(z^2) 0.0006154188   -0.01999045 1.028740 0.02986619 0.9705843  3 -143.2043 294.4087 304.8294
3  fit3 y = 0.093 - 0.248*poly(x, 3)1 - 0.186*poly(x, 3)2 - 0.581*poly(x, 3)3 - 0.031*z 0.0048717358   -0.03702840 1.037296 0.11627016 0.9764662  5 -142.9909 297.9819 313.6129
4  fit4        y = 0.201 + 0.08*ns(x, 3)1 - 0.385*ns(x, 3)2 - 0.281*ns(x, 3)3 - 0.031*z 0.0032813558   -0.03868575 1.038125 0.07818877 0.9887911  5 -143.0708 298.1416 313.7726
  deviance df.residual
1 102.5894          97
2 102.6556          97
3 102.2184          95
4 102.3818          95
```

Comment: Thank you all for your helps.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming `mods` shown in the Note at the end and that what is wanted is a character vector of a text representation of the formulas with the coefficients substituted we have the following.

The `fit2text` function takes a fitted object and outputs a character string with the text representation of the formula.  The `round` argument gives the number of digits that the coefficients are rounded to in the result.  The `rmI` argument, if TRUE, removes any I(...) and just leaves the ... inside assuming, for ease of implementation, that the expression inside does not contain any parentheses.  If FALSE then `I` is not removed.

Other statistics can be extracted from `summary(mods[[1]])` or `broom::glance(mods[[1]])`

```
fit2text <- function(fit, round = 2, rmI = TRUE) {
  fo <- formula(fit)  
  resp <- all.vars(fo)[1]
  co <- round(coef(fit), round)
  labs <- c(if (terms(fit, "intercept") == 1) "", labels(fit))
  p <- gsub("\\+ *-", "- ", paste(resp, "~ ", paste(paste(co, labs), collapse = " + ")))
  p2 <- if (rmI) gsub("I\\(([^)]+)\\)", "\\1", p) else p
  gsub(" +", " ", p2)
}
sapply(mods, fit2text)
```

giving:

```
                                                           fit1 
                                  "y ~ -0.11 - 0.05 x + 0.03 z" 
                                                           fit2 
                                "y ~ -0.07 - 0.05 x - 0.04 z^2" 
                                                           fit3 
"y ~ -0.11 - 0.43 poly(x, 3) - 1.05 z + 0.27 + 0.04 poly(x, 3)" 
                                                           fit4 
    "y ~ -0.55 + 0.23 ns(x, 3) + 0.79 z - 0.25 + 0.04 ns(x, 3)"
```

### Note

The code in the question was not reproducible because the library calls were missing, it used random numbers without a `set.seed` and there were some further errors in the code.  For clarity, we provide the following reproducible code that we used to provide the input for the above answer.

```
library(splines)
set.seed(123)

d <- data.frame(x = rnorm(100, 0, 1),
            y = rnorm(100, 0, 1),
            z = rnorm(100, 0, 1))

# function to fit 5 models
func <-function(d){
  fit1 <- lm( y~ x + z, data = d)
  fit2 <- lm( y~x + I(z^2), data = d)

  fit3 <- lm( y~poly(x,3) + z, data = d)
  fit4 <- lm( y~ns(x, 3) + z, data = d)
  l <- list(fit1, fit2, fit3, fit4)
  names(l) <- paste0("fit", 1:4) 
  return(l)
}

mods <- func(d)
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that each of your models is not exactly ideal for tabular data, for example fit 3 returns 4 estimates while fit 1 returns just 3

If you are comfortable with lists I would suggest they are a great way of storing this kind of information

```
library(broom)
library(tidyverse)
library(splines)

d <- data.frame(x = rnorm(100, 0, 1),
                y = rnorm(100, 0, 1),
                z = rnorm(100, 0, 1))

func <-function(d){
  fit1 <- lm( y~ x + z, data = d)
  fit2 <- lm( y~x + I(z^2), data = d)
  fit3 <- lm( y~poly(x,3) + z, data = d)
  fit4 <- lm( y~ns(x, 3) + z, data = d)
  l <- list(fit1, fit2, fit3, fit4)
  names(l) <- paste0("fit", 1:4) 
  return(l)
}

mods <- func(d) 

list_representation<- map(mods,tidy)
```