# Extract Formula From RIDGE, LASSO, and Net Elastic Regression with Coefficients (R) for many variables

Tags: r, linear-regression, formula, glmnet

**I am trying to modify some code that I found in one of the answers on this post:**

[Extract Formula From lm with Coefficients (R)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21269793/extract-formula-from-lm-with-coefficients-r)

**AlexB provided these wonderful lines of code:**

```
get_formula <- function(model) {
  broom::tidy(model)[, 1:2] %>%
    mutate(sign = ifelse(sign(estimate) == 1, ' + ', ' - ')) %>% #coeff signs
    mutate_if(is.numeric, ~ abs(round(., 2))) %>% #for improving formatting
    mutate(a = ifelse(term == '(Intercept)', paste0('y ~ ', estimate), paste0(sign, estimate, ' * ', term))) %>%
    summarise(formula = paste(a, collapse = '')) %>%
    as.character
}
```

**Though this works for some of my code, I am having issues adapting it to print formulas from glmnet models using RIDGE, LASSO, and Net Elastic Regression.**

## Attached below is an example of what I am trying to provide:

```
library(caret)
library(glmnet)
library(mlbench)
library(psych)
data("BostonHousing")
data <- BostonHousing
set.seed(23)
ind <- sample(2, nrow(data), replace = T, prob = c(0.7, 0.3))
train <- data[ind==1,]
test <- data[ind==2,]
custom <- trainControl(method = "repeatedcv",number = 10,repeats = 5,verboseIter = T)
set.seed(23)
ridge <- train(medv~., train,method = "glmnet",tuneGrid = expand.grid(alpha = 0,lambda = seq(0.0001,1,length = 5)),trControl = custom)
ridge
coef(ridge$finalModel, ridge$bestTune$lambda) # the coefficient estimates

get_formula <- function(model) {
  broom::tidy(model)[, 1:2] %>%
    mutate(sign = ifelse(sign(estimate) == 1, ' + ', ' - ')) %>% #coeff signs
    mutate_if(is.numeric, ~ abs(round(., 2))) %>% #for improving formatting
    mutate(a = ifelse(term == '(Intercept)', paste0('y ~ ', estimate), paste0(sign, estimate, ' * ', term))) %>%
    summarise(formula = paste(a, collapse = '')) %>%
    as.character
}
get_formula(ridge$finalModel)
```

However, given that it is not in the same format as in the previous post, I am having issues modifying the function so that it can print out the equations I am looking for.

## gives error :

```
Error: Problem with `mutate()` input `sign`.
x object 'estimate' not found
i Input `sign` is `ifelse(sign(estimate) == 1, " + ", " - ")`.
Run `rlang::last_error()` to see where the error occurred.
```

Thank kindly for the help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With minor updates, you can get the equation of a ridge regression, as follows:

```
as.matrix(coef(ridge$finalModel, ridge$bestTune$lambda)) %>%
  as.data.frame() %>%
  tibble::rownames_to_column('term') %>%
  rename(estimate = 2) %>%
  mutate(sign = ifelse(sign(estimate) == 1, ' + ', ' - ')) %>% #coeff signs
  mutate(across(where(is.numeric), ~abs(round(., 2)))) %>% #for improving formatting
  mutate(a = ifelse(term == '(Intercept)', paste0('y ~ ', estimate), paste0(sign, estimate, ' * ', term))) %>%
  summarise(formula = paste(a, collapse = ''))
```

Answer (score 0):

The `broom` package has [a `tidy` variant for `glmnet`](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/broom/versions/0.7.2/topics/tidy.glmnet) - you don't need to index into the tidied data with `[, 1:2]`.

Just use `tidy(model)` and the rest of the pipe will work just fine.

Here's the key part of the function, taken out for demonstration:

```r
broom::tidy(ridge$finalModel) %>%
  mutate(sign = ifelse(sign(estimate) == 1, ' + ', ' - ')) %>% #coeff signs
  mutate_if(is.numeric, ~ abs(round(., 2))) %>% #for improving formatting
  mutate(a = ifelse(term == '(Intercept)', paste0('y ~ ', estimate), paste0(sign, estimate, ' * ', term))) 

# A tibble: 1,400 x 7
   term         step estimate lambda dev.ratio sign  a        
   <chr>       <dbl>    <dbl>  <dbl>     <dbl> <chr> <chr>    
 1 (Intercept)     1     21.7  6655.      0    " + " y ~ 21.68
 2 (Intercept)     2     21.7  6064.      0.01 " + " y ~ 21.73
 3 (Intercept)     3     21.7  5525.      0.01 " + " y ~ 21.73
 4 (Intercept)     4     21.7  5034.      0.01 " + " y ~ 21.74
 5 (Intercept)     5     21.7  4587.      0.01 " + " y ~ 21.74
 6 (Intercept)     6     21.8  4180.      0.01 " + " y ~ 21.75
 7 (Intercept)     7     21.8  3808.      0.01 " + " y ~ 21.75
 8 (Intercept)     8     21.8  3470.      0.01 " + " y ~ 21.76
 9 (Intercept)     9     21.8  3162.      0.01 " + " y ~ 21.77
10 (Intercept)    10     21.8  2881.      0.02 " + " y ~ 21.78
# … with 1,390 more rows
```

Minor note: [`across`](https://dplyr.tidyverse.org/reference/across.html) can now replace `mutate_if`, e.g.

```r
mutate(across(where(is.numeric), ~abs(round(., 2))))
```

Comment: Dear Andrew, thanks kindly for your prompt response. I would greatly appreciate if you could further offer any advice with regards to structuring the code as to receiving one equation with the final model. It would contain only the information from this code: coef(ridge$finalModel, ridge$bestTune$lambda) # the coefficient estimates